# Node failed to connect MySQL without any error prompt

Tags: mysql, node.js, koa2

***The problem has been solved, but I'd like to leave this question with a deeper impression. Thanks for everyone!***

---

---

**update**
I found something wrong in `/src/mysql/index.js`, this code

```
/* this is wrong */
MySqlConnection.connect((error) => {
    /* old code */
    throw new Error(error.message);
    /* new code */
    error && new Error(error.message);
});
```

After modification, i'm connected to MySQL.But i still can't get correct return , i got nudefined...

---

I tried using node to connect MySQL and operate it, but i failed and get no error message.

I used koa2 and mysql from npm packages.

```
    "koa2": "^2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
```

My MySQL version is 8.0

I encapsulates a function to connect mysql, i'm sure that MySQL's configuration is useless.

```
    /* /src/mysql/index.js */
    const MySqlConnection = require("./mysql.index");
    /**
     *  connnect mysql
     * @param {string} sqlStatement sql statement
     * @param {object} params some required parameters
     * @param {function} callback if success
     */
    const MySqlOperator = (sqlStatement, params, callback) => {
        MySqlConnection.connect((error) => {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        });
        MySqlConnection.query(sqlStatement, params, (error, result, fieldValues) => {
            try {
                callback && callback(result, fieldValues);
            } catch {
                throw new Error(error.message);
            }
        });
        MySqlConnection.end();
        MySqlConnection.destroy();
    };

    module.exports = MySqlOperator;
```

and i use it like that

```
    const MySqlOperator = require("./src/mysql/MySql");
    // These three fields are all char types
    const sql = "INSERT INTO users(userUuid, userName, userPwd) values(1111，2222，3333);";

    MySqlOperator(sql, {}, (error, result, fliedValues) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        } else {
            /* here is undefined... */
            console.log(result, fliedValues);
        }
    });

    App.listen(ServerPort, () => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        console.log("start success");
    });
```

After I executed `node index.js`, node told me that he had successfully started, and terminal output `start success`, but the MySQL plug-in did not work and there was no error message.What can I do to successfully insert this data into MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you say this:

```
// These three fields are all char types
const sql = "INSERT INTO users(userUuid, userName, userPwd) values(1111，2222，3333);";
```

So I would advise you to respect types and modified this as:

```
const sql = "INSERT INTO users(userUuid, userName, userPwd) values('1111'，'2222'，'3333');";
```

And I think you have also a mistake in this part of */src/mysql/index.js* file:

```
        try {
            callback && callback(result, fieldValues);
        } catch {
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
```

Your original callback function accepts three arguments: **(error, result, fliedValues)** and you pass there your DB result as an error and because I suppose your query result will be without error (as **undefined**), then console.log(result, fliedValues); writes **undefined**.